# mySQL Clustered index: how do gaps in id values impact query performance

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, clustered-index

My data will be distributed among 50 databases with identical schema, let's say only one table ORDER (one DB for each of 50 clients) but each record must be globally identifiable. I plan to use numeric UID as PK.

My understanding is that mySQL will create a clustered index for this PK.

The data will always be inserted in monotonically increasing UID order.

Question about query performance: I have two choices when deciding how to generate uids. Which one will be better for query performance (within a given DB), or it doesn't matter?

1) For each client/database I assign a fixed hardcoded 'range' which will definitely be sufficient for all the future records there: I pick a really huge numeric range on the scale of 10^15 and within a range I start incrementing by one so that all UID values for this particular DB will be large but there will be no 'holes' between them

2) I use a globally shared HiLo generator for records in all databases, which means for a  given DB the records there will have a smaller value (compared to 10^15 scale in #1) but there will be more 'holes' between sequential UID records (or rather, between *batches* of UID: i.e. if the batch size is 100 there will be UIDs: 100,101,102,...199, and then 1400,1401,1402..1499, and then possibly 16000,16001,..16099)

Comment: Are you planning on hosting these 50 databases on 50 servers? Is this addressing a performance concern, or is this only mean to seaparate data (for privacy reasons)?

Comment: yes, because of privacy reasons they will have to be separate servers

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be adding an `instance_id` column to all tables, predetermined for each database, and use the standard auto_increment mechanism. The actual unique id for a record would be the tuple `(instance_id, autinc_val)`.

Comment: I am trying to avoid composite keys because they complicate things when communicating and coding, but thank you for proposing this solution